# Como faço para forçar onChange quando a página carrega?

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso forçar o onChange quando a página carrega, mas não estou conseguindo, já tentei jQuery e não funcionou.

Código do onChange:

```
let gruArrObj = [];

  let handleChangeSelectGrupoEDT = (value) => {
    setGrupoUid(value);

    gruArrObj.push({
      grupo_uuid: value,
    });

    //console.log(gruArrObj);

    const abc = grupos.filter(function (o1) {
      return gruArrObj.some(function (o2) {
        return o1.grupo_uuid === o2.grupo_uuid;
      });
    });

    //console.log(abc);
    // console.log(abc[0].gru_hab_tamanho);

    try {
      if (abc[0].gru_hab_tamanho === "S") {
        document.getElementById("adicionarTam").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("adicionarTam").style.display = "none";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      document.getElementById("adicionarTam").style.display = "none";
    }
  };
```

código onde chama o onChange:

```
<select
              value={grupoUid}
              onChange={(e) => handleChangeSelectGrupoEDT(e.target.value)}
              id="select-grupoEDT"
            >
              {grupos.map((grupo) => (
                <option value={grupo.grupo_uuid}>{grupo.gru_descricao}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
```

Quem puder ajudar, já agradeço.

Comment: a função **onload** não te ajuda? `<select onload="myFunction()">` ?

Comment: eu tentei, mas não funcionou também.

Comment: Tem a opção de executar por JS:
`<script>document.getElementById("myFrame").onload = function() {myFunction()};</script>`

Comment: ok, irei tentar

Comment: eu não entendi se poderia ser mais claro?

Comment: Acredito que chamando a função no ```constructor()```  no caso de um componente de classe, ou na começo da função principal, no caso de um componente funcional deveria funcionar